# Как эффективнее найти количество пар, чем O(n^2)

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, скорость

**Задача**: Дан массив натуральных чисел `a`. Найдите количество таких пар элементов `(a_i, a_j)`, где `abs(a_i − a_j) mod 200 == 0` и `i < j`

Я придумал такое решение:

```js
// n - the length of numbers array
// numbers - the array of natural numbers

function getNumberOfGoodPairs(n, numbers) {    
    let count = 0;
    const remainders = new Map();
    
    for (const num of numbers) {
        const remainder = num % 100;
        const modifiedNum = (num - remainder) / 100;
        
        if (remainders.has(remainder)) {
            const nums = remainders.get(remainder);
            
            for (const num of nums) {
                if (Math.abs(num - modifiedNum) % 2 === 0) ++count;
            }
            
            nums.push(modifiedNum);
        } else {
            remainders.set(remainder, [modifiedNum]);
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

**Обозначения**:

- `for (const arrayElement of array)` - получает элементы из `array` один за другим и помещает этот элемент в `arrayElement`. Это то же самое, что:

  ```js
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    const arrayElement = array[i];
  }
  ```
- `new Map()` - это словарь
- `%` - это `mod`
- `array.push(el)` - добавляет `el` В конец `array`
- `remainders.get(remainder)` - возвращает массив чисел, остаток которых равен `remainder` при делении на 100
- `remainders.set(remainder, [modifiedNum])` - добавляет в словарь новый ключ `remainder` и значение `[modifiedNum]`. `[modifiedNum]` - динамический массив с одним элементом `modifiedNum`

Если я прав, временная сложность в худшем случае будет `O(n^2)`

Пожалуйста, помогите мне оптимизировать этот алгоритм. Вы можете предоставить псевдокод для объяснения вашего алгоритма

Comment: 1. Вычисление `a MOD 200`. O(N). 2. Сортировка. O(N\*logN). 3. Выбор дубликатов и подсчёт. O(N). ИТОГО: O(N*logN)

Comment: @Akina 1. А как после сортировки гарантируется `i < j`? 2. Можете пожалуйста объяснить 3-ий пункт - подробнее?. Если не трудно, можете пожалуйста написать полноценный ответ почему вообще этот алгоритм будет работать?

Comment: *А как после сортировки гарантируется i < j?* Вы почитайте, что такое устойчивая сортировка. Да и не влияет это на окончательный ответ - вообще никак. *Можете пожалуйста объяснить 3-ий пункт - подробнее?* Да что тут пояснять-то? если остатки равны, то остаток разности нулевой. А из N чисел с одинаковым остатком можно составить ровно N*(N-1)/2 отвечающих всем условиям пар.

Comment: @Akina Устойчивая сортировка же сохраняет относительный порядок для элементов, имеющих одинаковые ключи, по которым происходит сортировка. А если они разные, то местами поменяются. Или из-за модуля разности нас это не интересует?

Comment: @Akina Спасибо!

Comment: Сортировка на ограниченном алфавите - *O(n)*. Например сортировка подсчетом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то с мапом или просто массивом на 200 элементов (`b`, заполненный нулями) задача решается за линейное время.

При обходе массива `а` вычисляете `m=a%200`  и добавляете к результату значение `b[m]`, потом увеличиваете `b[m]++`

```
import random
a = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(6)]
b = [0]*4
cnt = 0
for x in a:
    m = x%4
    cnt += b[m]
    b[m]+=1
print(a)
print(cnt)
```

пара примеров

```
[4, 8, 10, 7, 9, 6]
2

[3, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5]
3
```

Comment: `b[m]` - это массив чего?

Comment: Массив счётчиков элементов со значением m по модулю 200  (0..199), уже встреченных ранее

Comment: Я что-то запутался. Я гуляю по `a` и считаю `m=a[i]%200` и в массиве `b` (на 200 элементов заполненный изначально нулями) на позиции `m` делаю `b[m]++`? Если это верно, то что потом делаю с `b`?

Comment: "добавляете к результату значение b[m]" - тут суммируется ответ.

Comment: Сначала count += b[m], потом b[m]+=1

Comment: А разве надо сразу добавлять? Разве то что `b[m] == 1` не означает, что у числа пока что нет пары?

Comment: Да, надо добавлять сразу. Каждая новая единица в `b[m]` образует пары со всеми предыдущими единицами в том же `b[m]`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо всем!